# VBA OpenRecordset Produces Error 3061

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
databasename = "qryDataExport"
Dim grpfield As String
grpfield = "Group"

Dim keys As DAO.Recordset
groupcmd = "SELECT [" & databasename & "].[" & grpfield & "] FROM [" & databasename & "] GROUP BY [" & databasename & "].[" & grpfield & "]"
Set keys = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(groupcmd, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

The above produces "Error 3061: Too few parameters. Expected 13." when run. My reading thus far has heavily implied that this is likely a spelling issue with improper field titles or an issue caused by improper quotations in the line defining groupcmd.

I have attempted the following formats for databasename:

```
CurrentDb.Queries.qryDataExport
CurrentDb!Queries!qryDataExport
```

And the above `"qryDataExport"`. The latter two provide no error messages, while the first does not compile. I have confirmed that there is a column titled Group in both the main table and in qryDataExport.

The module being used is from [this Google Code page](http://code.google.com/p/access2kml/).

(EDIT: Full edited module as of this time: http://pastebin.com/TJip86ED)

From what I've seen, I expect this is an incredibly obvious formatting error in the databasename definition, but I haven't got enough experience with VBA to spot it and I'm running out of ideas. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT2: The content of `generateKML()` is now in `ExportToKMLButton_Click()`, where `ExportToKMLButton` is a Button on the Form `DW_Form`. While `DW_Form` is open, the query `qryDataExport` is usable, but when the form is closed, the query prompts for the 13 parameters mentioned in the error message.

Comment: Is this a direct copy and paste from your code?  Also do you have `Option Explicit` at the top of that module?  Additionally is there any chance your `qryDataExport` query is expecting parameters that you aren't giving to it?

Comment: Have you tried doing a debug.print on groupcmd and then taking the output and executing it from Access to see if that works?

Comment: Also, have you tried running "qryDataExport" on its own to make sure that that query actually runs?

Comment: Newd: The module is using Option Compare Database, but not Option Explicit. I suppose the query may be expecting further parameters; I'm not the one who wrote it and honestly don't know how to check parameter requirements.

Comment: OpiesDad: qryDataExport runs fine from the form (which has 16 inputs, so I don't believe that's likely to be it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like your *qryDataExport* query references controls on an Access form, perhaps similar to this one ...

```sql
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE some_field = Forms!Form1!YourTextBox
```

If *Form1* is open (in Form View), I can run that query from Access' query designer, and it will resolve the reference to the form control.

However, if I try to use the exact same query with `OpenRecordset`, the reference is not resolved and, in that context, Access interprets it to be a parameter for which I have not supplied a value.

For your query with multiple control references, you can create a temporary `QueryDef` based on your `SELECT` statement, and loop through its `Parameters` collection, supplying each parameter value with `Eval()` of the parameter's `.Name`  And finally call the `QueryDef.OpenRecordset` method to load your recordset:

```vb
Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, groupcmd)
For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
    prm.Value = Eval(prm.Name)
Next
Set keys = qdf.OpenRecordset
```

Comment: That seems to have done it! I'm still getting Error 3061, but it's on another OpenRecordset call now; the code here passes cleanly, at least.

Answer (score 0):

The way you use databasename is correct (`databasename = "qryDataExport"`), qryDataExport is likely filtering data using values from the form... that's why when you execute the query independently, the query finds it is missing 13 paramenters that it takes from said form.

You can run this procedure in a Click() event for a button within the form, it should work.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I'm afraid. I copied the contents of the generateKML() sub (which is what I was calling earlier) in as the sole content of the Click() event for the triggering button. This results in an identical error message.

Comment: Can you close all forms and try to open qryDataExport, what do you get?

Comment: It does indeed prompt for 13 parameters when operated in this way. I suppose this changes the question to how these values can be retrieved from the form; I assume that I need to be referencing fields as `Forms!DW_Form!fieldname` to retrieve these values in the Click event, but I'm not sure what to do with the groupcmd assignment from there.

Comment: Well, you have to have that form (DW_Form) open when you run the code, as I said in the answer one way would be to create a button to export within DW_Form and run your code on the Click event for that button as I said in the answer that should work.

Comment: That's what I've done now; triggering the method (previously Sub generateKML) from within the Click() event of ExportToKMLButton on DW_Form results in Error 3061 on the line `Set keys (...)` as shown in the above example. The Click() method takes no parameters; could this be part of the problem?

Comment: Another way would be to define parameters for the query as explained here https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Use-parameters-in-queries-and-reports-8209eb5c-1589-42e2-9b20-4181f4c7a356, and using QueryDefs to pass the parameters in VBA as in here http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/199671-passing-parameters-select-query-vba