# Error '3061' to few parameters. On button to open weblink with google maps waypoints

Tags: vba, ms-access

Im building a button to open googlemaps with waypoints marked of all the points in my subform.  On click however I keep getting 
Run-time error '3061':
Too few parameters. Expected 1

code below

```
    Private Sub Route_Plan_Click()
Dim strHyperlink As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("export_query")
    strHyperlink = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=','start point address>,+'<start postcode>'"
 If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF = True
    strHyperlink = strHyperlink & "&waypoints=" & i & "='" & rs!Address & "',+'" & rs!Postcode & "'"
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
 End If
Application.FollowHyperlink (strHyperlink)
MsgBox "Finished looping through records."
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

the form sets a query record source  which I am looping through to create the string for the weblink but am at a loss on why I am getting this error if anyone has any advice or suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At which line are you getting the error? If it's the line starting with `Set rs`, your query probably needs parameters you aren't providing, and you will need to either adjust your query or provide the required parameter.

Comment: Is your rs!Address and rs!PostalCode is received in excel?

Comment: you are correct it is at the SET rs

Answer (score 0):

Open the query `export_query` directly in Access, it will request missing data and you will be able to determine where is the problem. Usually parameter request appears when query contains wrong column names.

Comment: It looks like the problem is the query has parameters from form controls, though the form is open it fails on openrecordset

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it thanks to this thread 
[VBA OpenRecordset Produces Error 3061](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378074/vba-openrecordset-produces-error-3061)

Added this into it code

```
Dim prm As DAO.Parameter 
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef 

export_query = "Select export_query.address, export_query.postcode from export_query" 
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, export_query) 
For Each prm In qdf.Parameters 
    prm.Value = Eval(prm.Name) 
Next 
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset
```